# IE10 makes ASPX menu disappear underneath main div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

Since we changed from IE8 to IE10 we have a problem with the menu in a WebForms app. In IE10 compatibility mode everything is fine, but in normal mode when the ASPX menu is expanded on hover it disappears underneath our main div, which makes it unclickable.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: You'll have to share code...

Comment: While we wait for your code, I'll have a guess: you don't have z-index set on the menu.

Comment: possibly related to this: http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: have you tried `z-index` yet? you have no JSfiddle or code posted so I'm recommending blind. But also keep in mind that ASPX and IE10 and 11 do not get along. We have many issues with ASP and ASPX here at my company.

Comment: @racecarjonathan Yeah, z-index does not help. :)

Comment: @mfreitas I will tomorrow.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright Thanks for the link. That *is* what is happening. I did try the z-index on the div surrounding the menu. Since the menu is generated by ASPX it is more difficult to set z-indexes on those elements, but it must be possible. I willt try tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2609980 Should be possible, drop your code into a JSFiddle and we should be able to work it out :)